# Escape colon in url string

Tags: php

I have a string:

```
$fonts = "Arial:400";
```

When I use that in a URL, the colon prints as %3A.  How can I escape the colon so that it prints as `:`?  I have tried preg_replace and urlencode with no luck.  I'm sure its simple but I have searched.

Comment: did you try urldecode ?

Comment: `Arial:400` is not a string.  `"Arial:400"` is though.

Comment: Please visit next:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript

Comment: You want to print url or put the colon contained url in address bar?

Comment: @EduardoCuomo thats js, not php

Comment: @EduardoCuomo thats js, not php Sorry! http://php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Yes, I have tried urldecode as well.  @vkas, I need the the colon to print in the url.

Comment: @EduardoCuomo urlencode isnt doing the trick.

Comment: Print where? In the location bar? Inside the page?

Comment: The url is being echoed into a stylesheet link in the head of the document.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using urlencode and substitute the %3a with :

```
$url = urlencode($url);
$url = str_replace("%3A",":",$url);
```

Comment: I thought this might be it but its not doing it either.