# PHP not able to redirect to url which contains colon

Tags: php

I am trying to redirect to url

```
<?php
$url = "https://icommand://?username=Sachin";
header("Location: ".$url."");
?>
```

But when I try this one it redirect to me this url 
http://icommand//?username=Sachin. The colon does not come after icommand.
I have tried but doesn't get solution.

Comment: A quick search found this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060002/escape-colon-in-url-string - Google is your friend

Comment: why would you redirect to icommand:  that makes no sense. I think your browser removes the :

Comment: what's the trailing colon supposed to do? after the colon should go the port number.. something like `https://icommand:443/`

Comment: Try usnig only `icommand://?username=Sachin`

Comment: It may be because that's not a valid URL. A colon is not allowed in the hostname

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
<?php
     $url = "//icommand://?username=Sachin";
     header("Location: ".$url."");
?>
```

Comment: No, it is not working.....http://icommand//?username=Sachin. The colon has removed.

Answer (score 1):

try this: urlencode();

```
$url = "//icommand://?username=Sachin";
header("Location: ".urlencode($url)."");
```

Comment: It's wrong. It is redirecting to http://localhost/test/%2F%2Ficommand%3A%2F%2F%3Fusername%3DSachin

Comment: this url is "url encoded" all the special symbol are encoded when you decode the url you will get the same "//icommand://?username=Sachin" refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php